# HTML 5 test for new elements

Tags: html

How can I test if my browser supports the new semantic HTML 5 elements like:

```
<nav>
<footer>
```

and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick, non-programming check: [The HTML5 Test](http://www.html5test.com/)

Comment: Thanks I've read all the code in that source page...and I can
test with some statements like this (also if the author's site made it differently...): 
var element = document.createElement("nav");
element.toString() == "[object HTMLUnknownElement]"

Answer (score 4):

[Dive Into HTML5 > Detecting HTML5 Features](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html):

> There are four basic techniques for detecting whether a browser supports a particular feature. From simplest to most complex:
>
> 1. Check if a certain property exists on a global object (such as window or navigator).
>
>    Example: [testing for geolocation support](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#geolocation)
> 2. Create an element, then check if a certain property exists on that element.
>
>    Example: [testing for canvas support](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#canvas)
> 3. Create an element, check if a certain method exists on that element, then call the method and check the value it returns.
>
>    Example: [testing which video formats are supported](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video-formats)
> 4. Create an element, set a property to a certain value, then check if the property retained its value.
>
>    Example: [testing which `<input>` types are supported](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types)

Also, there is

> [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), an open source, MIT-licensed JavaScript library that detects support for many HTML5 & CSS3 features.

Plus:

> [Appendix A: The All-In-One Almost-Alphabetical No-Bullshit Guide to Detecting Everything](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html).